# How to get current user permissions using JIRA SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, jira

I'm developing a JIRA Client using the SOAP API and I want to check in advance what features the user will have available.

For example I don't want to show a button to comment on an issue if the user doesn't have   Add Comments **RemotePermission**.

I tried with **getAllPermissions** method, but it seems it gets all permissions int the application, not the ones that the user has.

Answer (score 0):

Not easy. There is a method for checking comment permission in 4.4 but not for all permissions in general, IIRC.

http://docs.atlassian.com/rpc-jira-plugin/4.4/com/atlassian/jira/rpc/soap/JiraSoapService.html#hasPermissionToEditComment(java.lang.String, com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.beans.RemoteComment)

Better to go with REST if you can.

Comment: Thanks, but those methods are not enough for me, I wanted to check for add comment permission, work on issue permission, and more.

EDIT: Thanks for pointing out REST API, when I first looked into it it was very incomplete, but it seems they added a lot of methods now, one of those: /jira/rest/api/2/mypermissions looks that will work for me.